# npm WARN @ionic/cli-plugin-core@0.0.6 requires a peer of @ionic/app-scripts@^1.1.0 but none was installed

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, ionic2

I keep getting

`npm WARN @ionic/cli-plugin-core@0.0.6 requires a peer of @ionic/app-scripts@^1.1.0 but none was installed`

[image]

I tried deleting the node_modules folder, npm cache clean, npm install all module,npm install. Nothing worked. I'm using ionic2.

Please note, that everything was working on someone else's laptop, copied the entire folder on mine, stopped working.

Ionic version on my laptop

[image]

The other laptop is not mine to check but I was told that it has the same version.

Comment: Could you give us more info on what version of Ionic are you using and the version of your ionic-cli.. ? (It would also be better if you had a look at the someone else's laptop's Ionic versions)

Comment: @RajaYogan sure tomorrow cz not on pc now

Comment: @RajaYogan question edited

Comment: Not sure what your error is about.. but I can see that you have tried installing cli-plugin-latest by yourself and failed. Can you try that again with two --save (two hyphens, don't copy paste, type it yourself)

Comment: After installing the latest cli-plugin-ionic-angular try npm install from your ionic project.. (Alternatively you could just remove and reinstall the ionic cli and try again)